# Java SWT: Using custom .otf/ .ttf fonts

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, swt, executable-jar

I have recently made the change from JavaFX to SWT. It is faster.
However, I am having a hard time getting custom fonts to work from *inside* my runnable JAR.

Getting it to work with JavaFX was also challenging (Could not find any official documentation on how I had to refer to the actual defined font name in the CSS to get it to work).

However, the problem I have now is that the SWT Font class does not accept a File of the custom font. Just the path. Therefore, if I try to open the font resource as a Stream, it won't work. If I refer to it by placing it in the package (Then I could simply refer to the path as `"customFont.otf"`), it still won't detect the path and register the font.

The only way I am able to get it to work **outside** the IDE as a solo runnable JAR file is by reading the file as a Stream, writing it to some location outside, and then referring to that path. Then on application close, I am removing the font file. I would like to avoid this since I do not want to create any files as the JAR runs.

Could it be that JavaFX does the same thing but in the background without my awareness, even when I am reading resource as a Stream? I don't want my JAR to access anything from outside the program stack. I want to be able to access all resources from within the program stack since my program is of small-scale.

I am on **Windows 10 x64** & following SWT instructions:

```
boolean loadFont = shell.getDisplay().loadFont("appfont.otf");
if(loadFont)
{
    Font f = new Font(shell.getDisplay(), "appfont", 18, SWT.NORMAL);
    textDisplay.setFont(f);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Font wasn't loaded.");
}
```

This top code works **inside** the IDE.

But it does not work on the JAR since there is no such path in the compiled JAR.
Would I somehow be able to refer to it canonically?

I would have expected the font file to be loaded on to the program stack at the very least when the related instruction was loaded on to PCB.

Could it be that the ultimate issue is boiling down to simply how to access resources from within JAR or whether a JAR even has a solid file structure?

### EDIT

I forgot to mention that I did attempt a solution that involved

```
org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;

new GC().getDevice();
```

But I did not get very far. I am still working on it, but could this be the way to the solution?

FOLLOWUP

The aformentioned endeavour failed. Failed to work in IDE. I implemented

```
GC gc = new GC(shell);
boolean loadFont = shell.getDisplay().loadFont("appfont.otf");
if(loadFont)
{
    Font f = new Font(gc.getDevice(), "uifont.otf", 12, SWT.NORMAL);
    gc.setFont(f);
}
```

PROGRAM CODE FOR TESTING

For your convenience, below is the entire code for the SWT. It is simply a minimal window with a menubar & a text display. The custom font is not loaded and the program launches with default font.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class MainWindow
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("APP");
        GridLayout mainLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        shell.setLayout(mainLayout);
        //----
        GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        Text textDisplay = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        textDisplay.setLayoutData(gd);

        boolean loadFont = shell.getDisplay().loadFont("src/appfont.otf");
        if(loadFont)
        {
            Font f = new Font(shell.getDisplay(), "appfont.otf", 18, SWT.NORMAL);
            textDisplay.setFont(f);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }

        Menu menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
        MenuItem fileMenuLabel = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileMenuLabel.setText("File");

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        fileMenuLabel.setMenu(fileMenu);

        MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem(fileMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        saveFile.setText("Edit");

        saveFile.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                if(saveFile.getText().equals("Edit"))
                {
                    saveFile.setText("Save");
                    textDisplay.setEditable(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    saveFile.setText("Edit");
                    textDisplay.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        //----
        shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
        shell.open();

        while(!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `getSystemResource()` not `getResource()`.

Comment: Please disregard that, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue and have removed that section from the question.

Comment: Can't you put the OTF into the JAR?

Comment: I have the .otf inside my eclipse project. I think it mainly boils down to how to access it, since I don't know the path of that file from inside the JAR. The canonical path that worked in the IDE won't work on the JAR.

Comment: Is it in a _resources_ folder?  Have you confirmed it's actually written into the JAR?  You have to use `getResource()` or `getSystemResource()` to pull it out of a JAR (or classpath respectively) at runtime.

Comment: No, I have placed it inside my package and just outside in the project folder. The latter works. If I were to place it in a resources folder, would I refer to is as ```folderName/fileName```? I will try this now

Comment: Previously, I tried to pull it out like that, but from those directories, and the result was it could not be found from thos paths.

Comment: I'd be confirming it's ending up in the JAR then you can see where to find it ... There's an idiom using getResource() - just can't find a good example at the moment.

Comment: I did use getResource() then getPath() on that but it didn't work. To bring in more hassle, the loadFont() method of SWT accepts a File path String or a File object. But I just tried it by setting a resources folder in Eclipse and acessing it from there, it returns a Null Pointer meaning it wasn't able to find the .otf. I made sure I linked the folder as a resource in Eclipse project settings as well.

Comment: Does SO allow linking a java file for you to test & run?

Comment: Of what a bummer (SWT only works with local filesystem) - found this if it helps https://coderwall.com/p/d0kssw/resource-extraction-from-jar-to-local-file-system.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work. I will read the article, but if you wish to run an actual instance of the program, I have added it to the original question.

Comment: If you feel this is the final answer, please post it as such and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Was a short read, great find. How sad, I really liked the speed too, looks like it's back to JavaFX

Comment: The SWT Device.loadFont call is just a thin wrapper around the appropriate OS API (for example on macOS it uses `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`). For this reason it only supports a plain file path.

Comment: Could you expand on what a plain file path is?

Comment: Just a file in the in file system. The contents of Jars are not part of the file system. You would have to extract the font to a temporary file. For a plain SWT app you would have to do that, for an Eclipse RCP the plug-in manager can do it for you.

Comment: Are you sure SWT doesn't support the "jar:pathinjar/yourresource" style path? I have a vague memory of getting a "path" that looked something like that...

Comment: I see, how disappointing, I did not want extra files being created. Is using SWT with JFace the same way? The only other option for me would be GTK+ but I don't want to go through the hassle with MySys2, etc.

Comment: @MrR Some Java things support that but not this code since the path is passed to a OS API which doesn't understand such things.

Comment: I still cannot get over this, SWT was so perfect. Speed, portability and everything.

Comment: @mindoverflow - have a look at the source (SWT) before hari-kiri .. maybe you can override something / or make a small change?

Comment: @MrR Changing SWT code is generally not easy. The source is completely different on each OS.

Comment: Haha I am a very inexperienced developer. At this point, the time it would take for me to inspect and comprehend source code would not be beneficial.

Comment: I was able to get it working through the ugly procedure of getting the file from JAR, writing it to local and then removing it on app close, but seems so unrefined.

Comment: Actually that sort of unpacking happens all the time for various reasons - which is why the Eclipse plug-in manager provides a standard way to do it.

Comment: Does JavaFX do this as well, but just hides it from me? I was thinking it was being accessed from stack since the resources are miniscule.

Comment: @greg-449 yes I see what you mean .. I grabbed the eclipse code and loved how there's nothing in common across platforms for that stuff (other than class names and public methods !!).

Comment: I just want a decent GUI, JavaFX - slow, Swing - ugly and layouts are a mess, GTK - Linux bound, Electron - JS support required. How to they make apps like SublimeText look so good, I doubt they make their own GUI engine... Notepad++ changes fonts no problem. What GUI does that program use? Very little information on this across the Internet.

Comment: I don't know what those apps use. Personally I use the Eclipse 'e4' RCP - this is the core Eclipse code with SWT.

Comment: @greg-449 hello there, this is quite some time after the question was asked, but at that time i was not experienced enough to comprehend eclipse RCP. i noticed that you're heavily involved in this field. now that i have grown older, i was wondering if you had any other resource except official documentation regarding rcp. thank you.

Comment: The vogella.com tutorials are usually good, for example https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html